# How to mimic javax rs' WebTarget's 'property' in curl?

Tags: java, curl, jax-rs

I have a GET request made from jaxrs, which looks like this:

```
final Response response = client.target(SERVICE_URL)
                .path(String.format("/test/testView/-/%d/%d", a, b))
                .request()
                .property("Service", "MyService")
                .property("Operation", "Query")
                 .header("x-client-id", "MyClientId")
                .get();
```

I want to mimic this query using curl. I can send the header using `-H` but I am not sure how to send these properties using curl. Any pointers?

Comment: There's no such thing as a property in http. This is something specifically for the WebTarget to set some arbitrary property for other components to access.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Ohkay. But this is going as a GET request right? Meaning the information should be in the URL. So the WebTarget must modify the `property` to something as the URL. Any pointers there?

Comment: No. Nothing will happen with those custom properties unless you decide to do something with them inside some filter or something. Right now, if you yourself don't do something with them, they're just throwaway values

Comment: Maybe you're thinking about query parameters. Those are totally different. You would use the `queryParam()` method for those.